# How to force Spyder or any IDE to reload python modules/files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am checking someone else code and I could not figure out how to make it work. I need to reload the whole modules and sometimes it does it sometimes it does not.

The folder structure is as shown below:

```
Parent Folder
-> Folder jobs
   -> plant_trans.py
-> Folder scripts
   -> __init__.py
   -> connect.py
```

I need to run a script in `jobs` folder.

The script is named `plant_trans.py` and contains `import scripts` on top.

When I run it, i get an error at line:

```
with scripts.connect.get_connection(DB_NAME) as td_con:
```

Error:

```
with scripts.connect.get_connection(DB_NAME) as td_con:

AttributeError: module 'scripts' has no attribute 'connect'
```

My guess is because the reload is not working when I run the `plant_trans.py` file. Sometimes I did get the reload modules etc notice and it worked but I cannot force it to reload the modules whenever I want. Any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to use `PYTHONPATH` and set it to the `Parent Folder` level

In Spyder, the option is available at `Tools -> PYTHONPATH Manager`

[image: PYTHONPATH Spyder]

Click on `+ Add path` and paste the `Parent Folder` there. Also, click on the `Synchronize..` afterwards

[image]